# How does StockTwits support OpenGraph for posted URLs?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, stocktwits

When i try to post url http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/05/02/apple-cruises-past-old-market-capitalization-record-may-hit-800-billion-before-earnings
i did not get any preview in StockTwits,

[image: Url Posted to StockTwits]

while it looks good in Twitter
[image: Url Posted to Twitter]

On other hand when i post some YouTube video to StockTwits it show preview
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLzJ3OGU07A

[image: YouTube preview in StockTwits]

**Question**: Which of OpenGraph meta-tags support StockTwits?

I have already added

```html
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="site Inc." />  
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://test.com/image/279205d5-9a89-40d1-9c13-5fb255b16754?t=42855.682442245372"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://test.com:80/279205d5-9a89-40d1-9c13-5fb255b16754" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="My description"/>
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://test.com/image/279205d5-9a89-40d1-9c13-5fb255b16754?t=42855.682442245372"/>
```

It works for Twitter, but does not help for StockTwits =(